# Delete a Simple row from database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 2 tables, `testInput` and `testCases` and in `testInput` i have a FK with the id of the other table.

So basically the rows I want to delete are id of the input, id of the testCase, name and a description.

```
'43', '21', 'USERNAME', 'USERNAME'
'44', '21', 'PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD'
```

I tried to delete that row and I get

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`mydb`.`testInput`, CONSTRAINT `fk02` FOREIGN KEY (`testCase`)
>   REFERENCES `testCases` (`idtestCase`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION)

**I don't want to delete the record of testCase. I just want to delete the inputs of that testCase. What do I do?**

code if u want...

```
  List<TestInput> previousInputs = TestInput.getInputs(testCaseName);
        for(TestInput in : previousInputs) {
            Database.deleteObject(in);
        }



 //delete the object to the database
public static void deleteObject(Object object) {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(object);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

xml TestCases

```
   <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="TestCase" table="testCases">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the testCases details.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="idtestCase">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="type" class="TestType" column="type" fetch="select" lazy="false"/>
    <property name="data" column="data" type="binary"/>
    <property name="amountOfInputs" column="amountOfInputs" type="int"/>
    <property name="creationDate" column="creationDate" type="string"/>
    <property name="createdBy" column="createdBy" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="tellerConfig" class="TellerConfiguration" column="tellerConfig" fetch="select" lazy="false"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

xml testInput

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="TestInput" table="testInput">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the testCases input details.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="idtestInput">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    <property name="description" column="description" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="testCase" class="TestCase" column="testCase" fetch="select" cascade="all" lazy="false" />
</class>
```

Comment: Your mapped classes could also be useful

Comment: I will edit....

Comment: try removing the `cascade=all` from your manyToOne, and replace it by every 'useful' one for you (persist, merge, refresh,...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to resolve this on a database level by changing how the foreign key `fk02` is defined, that is replace 'ON DELETE NO ACTION' with something more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constraint on the foreign key fk02 from ´NO ACTION´ to 'SET NULL'

```
FOREIGN KEY (idtestcase)
REFERENCES testCases(idtestCase)
ON DELETE SET NULL
```